# Is there anyway to log Firebug 'profile' results to an external file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

Specifically, we've got some external JavaScript tracking code on our sites that throws itself into an infinite loop each time an anchor is clicked on.

We don't maintain the tracking code, so we don't know exactly how it works.  Since the code causes the browser to lock up almost immediately, I was wondering if there's anyway to log the results of Firebug's 'profile' functionality to an external file for review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to narrow it down by setting breakpoints in the offending JavaScript. It might be messy (especially if they "minify" their JavaScript), but I think it's your best bet.

Comment: unfortunately, their code is obfuscated to the point of unreadability, so I wouldn't have any bearing to place the breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps by modifying firebug itself, or creating a firebug plugin, you could log the data to a preferences or sqllite.  But firefox doesn't grant write access to plain old javascript.

Comment: hmm, I figured this would be the only solution, unfortunately :(  Thanks, though.